# Bugs in Red5 RC2?

Tags: flash, red5

I have installed the Windows version of Red5 RC2 and am running the server. I have, unfortunately, noticed 
some interesting problems with the distribution:

1. The windows install version of this release candidate does not have the demo applications. The entire
   demos folder is not included. There is a link to it on the main Red5 app page, but the link goes nowhere.
   I actually had to download a zip file with a previous version of Red5 in order to acquire the demos 
   folder. If someone at Red5 is reading this, could you please correct this oversight?
2. There is some weird port- handling behavior when you run the server. When running the server, I get
   several JVM_Bind errors -- until I make changes to the ports in the red5.properties file. I have to
   change the http.port entry and the jmx.rmi.port entry. Only by changing these ports do I seem to get the
   server to run properly. What is really strange, though, is that I am running the server on a laptop
   which I periodically shut down. If I boot the laptop and run Red5 again, I get the JVM_Bind errors again!
   This despite the fact that I am pointing it to different ports. I have found that I can then change back
   to the old port numbers and Red5 starts up without problems. So now on jmx.rmi.port I alternate between
   port 4444 and 9999. On http.port I alternate between Port 8080 and 8081. In any event, there appears to
   be something in the server that somehow "thinks" that a previously used port is still in use. Some kind
   of cache? If so, is there any way to clear it so that I won't have to change ports all the time?
3. Once I get the server running with the proper demos folder in place, the demos seem to work well -- as
   long as I am running everything on the same machine. For some reason, however, the server does not 
   respond to http requests from other machines. This is clearly some kind of configuration issue, but the
   documentation that I have read so far dos not tell how to make Red5 handle requests from anywhere other
   than localhost. I would like to run the demo apps on the same machine and other machines. Is there any
   documentation on how to make this so? Could someone tell me where that documentation is?

These are the things I have seen so far with Red5. It looks like it has a lot of potential, but it 
looks like there are some real bugs in the server. Is this correct or is there some kind of setup or 
configuration that will make these problems go away?

```
Someone please advise.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

about question No 3:

Red5 has only several files where you can configure the listening interface:
conf/red5.properties

```
0.0.0.0
```

Means it is listening to ALL interfaces.

And you can configure also each webapp, in:
webapps/$NAME_OF_APP/WEB-INF/red5-web.properties

```
webapp.virtualHosts=*
```

Means it is listening to ALL interfaces.

Thats basically it, if you have configured those ports, you can control the listening ports with the commmand:

```
netstat -an
```

It will list you all listeing ports.
And you might find something like:

```
tcp46      0      0  *.8088                 *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp46      0      0  *.5080                 *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp46      0      0  *.1935                 *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp46      0      0  *.9999                 *.*                    LISTEN
```

(those are of course a lot more lines then these, but those are my locally configured red5 listening ports).

Sebastian

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, the syntax of the webapp.virtualHost entries is not clear. For example: in the red5.properties file I am seeing the line: webapp.virtualHosts=*, localhost, localhost:8088, 127.0.0.1:8088, but in my vod application's red5-web.properties file I am getting webapp.virtualHosts=*. So which properties file overrides the other? Also: doesn't the '*' mean that all machines have access to the application? If so, then why doesn't red5 respond when a request comes from another machine???

Comment: I have another question: does Red5 do anything to "persist" a network listener on Windows? The reason for this question is that I have been doing a netstat -anb and am seeing a listener allocated to a java.exe process. What is weird because when I see this there is no java process running! I tested things by setting Red5's jmx.rmi.port setting in red5.properties, then running Red5, then rebooting my system, then immediately doing a netstat -anb. netstat shows the jmx port that I had previously set as being active! Have I found a bug in Red5's port handling???

Comment: Continuing my question: Red5's jmx subsystem seems to grab a port and doesn't release it when Red5 is stopped. This happens on Windows 7. The port stays "grabbed" when the system is rebooted, causing Red5 to throw JVM_Bind exceptions when it attempts to get the port. So is this a bug and how do I report it? Also, how do I deallocate a port number that "thinks" it is allocated to a non- running system so that I won't keep having to change the jmx port every time I start Red5???

Comment: I am using Windows7 too, Red5 does not persist a network listener, and it does release all ports as soon as its stopped.

Comment: What are you using to start/stop red5? I am simply using the provided .bat file, no windows service.

Comment: I am using the file red5-shutdown.bat -- when my jmx port is set to 9999. Unfortunately since I had been switching that port between 9999 and 4444, the batch file doesn't always work. I have researched the problem, though, and learned that these "persistent" port allocations are usually caused by applications spawning processes or threads and then either crashing or abruptly stopping. It seems to be a Windows problem that many multithreaded networking apps compensate for. Red5 spawns off a lot of threads. Does the jmx mechanism properly release network resources after shutting down Red5?

Comment: I ask the kast question because it is the jmx port that seems to be locked up between reboots. Whichever port was used as the jmx port keeps showing as being used by a nonexistent java process after reboot of the system, so the problem must have something to do with Red5's jmx code.

Comment: One other question: how does one configure the webapp.virtualHost property so that Red5 can work with other machines? tt is clear that the current configuration isn't allowing this, even though the applications have webapp.virtualHost set to '*'...

Comment: you have a network or firewall issue, there is nothing else to configure. Full stop ;)  If you have been installing the windows installer and configured it as a windows service things might be different, but as long as you simply use the red5.bat to start stop it, there is nothing else to look at. Maybe you've started red5 multiple times and that is why there are still resources aquired by red5.

Comment: red5-shutdown.bat will not do that much, simply use red5.bat, let the cmd window open as long as you want to use red5, and if you're finished simply close that CMD and red5 is gone.

Comment: OOPS -- Sorry, I meant that I use red5-shutdown to shut down red5. I use red5.bat to start it. And no: I am not starting multiple red5 processes. I start it once, and when I am done with it I shut it down. I did some research, then today when I rebooted I used ProcessExplorer to identify the (non) process that is holding the port. the process was initiated by an executable called wrapper.exe -- a file that resides in red5's server directory. When I use ProcessExplorer to kill this process tree (the process does not show up on Windows' task manager), then Red5 starts up normally.

Comment: On the other question: it turns out that it wasn't a firewall or network issue. It was an "I screwed up" issue. I changed the wrong property in the red5.properties file, so that the HTTP host was still localhost. Once that was corrected, the pages worked without problems. Thanks for your patience on this...